# Where is symbol server utility located in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, debug-symbols

I installed Visual Studio v120 into "D:\dev\visualstudio" because I need SDK tools installed inside "no spaces dir", now I'm having problem to locate a utility that is used to check Microsoft Symbols server.

What is the name of utility? and where is it located?
I need to find it in order to allow outbound firewall rule.

I tried searching for "symchk" but there is no such file, is it renamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft debuggers tend to use symbol paths to attempt to resolve symbols in a binary. Full documentation can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx

Examine the relative section.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think the problem is that my Visual Studio does not ship with debugging tools for some reason?? even though I installed ultimate :confused

Comment: Windbg is the team that does the core debugging experience, and Visual Studio mostly wraps it and pretty prints its output. (There's vshost, but that's a distraction at this point) Download here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx The main thing is to get the symbol paths correct. For released core symbols, you can follow http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503 and for your own symbols, make sure they are in the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH, or add them to the path in Visual Studio under the symbol paths setting.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for answering my own question but, I managed to find [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=VS.85).aspx):

> Debugging environments
>
> After you install Visual Studio and the WDK, you'll have six available
>   debugging environments. All of these debugging environments provide
>   user interfaces for the same underlying debugging engine, which is
>   implemented in dbgeng.dll. This debugging engine is called the Windows
>   debugger, and the six debugging environments are collectively called
>   the Windows debuggers.
>
> Note  Visual Studio includes its own debugging environment and
>   debugging engine, which together are called the Visual Studio
>   debugger. The Visual Studio debugger is completely different from
>   Windows debugger.

Obviously what I'm missing here is Windows debugging tools ^^
Visual Studio debugger can not download symbols.